# image uploading done but no response

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova, multifile-uploader

i'm going to send a image from phone gap android app to a web server. i've a js file like that:

```
         function uploadPic(imageURI,objectId){
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="text/plain";

        var upload_url="http://services.jhj.nl:2357/TWMSServic
         /upload?token="+objectId+"&filenaam="+options.fileName+".jpg";
        alert(upload_url);
        alert(options.fileName);
        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, upload_url, picUploadSuccess, picUploadFailed, options);
      }
       function picUploadSuccess(r){
         alert("Upload Done");
         alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
         alert("Response = " + r.response);
          alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
           alert(r.response);
         }
```

Now i've faced a problem that is when i send image to server it alert Upload Done,bytesSent and Upload Done correctly.i've got some update image uploaded to the server. but it has some extra data for that image can not be open. if i delete those extra data then it open properly.please give some ideas... thanks in advance....